# Same object as const and non-const, what should I assume to behave correctly?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, constants, standards

I have a function of the form

```
return_type function(const argument_type & a, argument_type & b);
```

If the same object is passed as `a` and `b`,  can I proceed with the function (thereby potentially modifying it) or halt?

I don't have the knowledge about how the compiler assumptions propagate on that case.

My guess is that non-constness assumptions for it being passed as non-const `b` should suffice and allow the modifications, but it's a guess.

---

Most answers were about being *able* to modify `a` or `b`, or call non-const methods. I know that if I pass the same object as both `const` and `non-const` I can do that. My doubt lies more in state that I'm going to left the program when the function returns, and if it can brake some compiler assumptions, for example:

```
class A(){
    int value;
}

void function1(const A & arg1);
void function2(A & arg1);
void function3(const A & arg1, A & arg2);

A a;
a.value=5;
function1(a);
if(a.value==5){/*...*/;} // the if can be optimized out to true, because [a] was const

a.value=5;
function2(a);
if(a.value==5){/*...*/;} //must be checked, [a] could have been modified

a.value=5;
function3(a, a);
if(a.value==5){/*...*/;} // ???
```

---

Most similar question I've found (but not really it)

[Modifying self within const method via non const pointer to self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053806/modifying-self-within-const-method-via-non-const-pointer-to-self)

Comment: Your code does not change memory per se, but it changes memory represented by a variable. The compiler takes care of variable constant-ness (?) not during executing but compilation. That indicates that yes, you can change memory pointed by a by modyficaiton of b, if a and b point to the same memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with

```
return_type function(const argument_type & a, argument_type & b);
```

and a call `function( o , o )` is that the function probably

- modifies the object through formal argument `b`, while
- at the same time expecting formal argument `a` to remain unchanged.

So you will probably break the assumptions of the function, resulting in e.g. incorrect results or a crash.

---

There is one function that *by design* often has this kind of signature, namely the copy assignment operator. Its constant formal argument `a` is the explicity provided argument, and its mutable formal argument (if one can call it that) is the implicit `*this`. It can either check for self-reference (aliasing of the arguments) or it can copy and swap.

---

In summary, whether you can safely call the function with the same object as argument `a` and as argument `b` depends on the function, but chances are that you will violate the function's assumptions, that it has as an implicit precondition that the formal arguments refer to different objects.

Comment: Will edit my question to clarify to other answers the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You decide if that function may be called with the same argument given twice.
Anyway, you should not try to determine if you get the same object twice, as long as the correctness of your algorithm does not depend on it or you gave no guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

They are passed exactly the same way at run time, same reference/pointer to exactly the same thing.

The difference with `const` happens only at compile time. The compiler will make sure you are calling only `const` methods and not trying to modify properties of this `const` object, otherwise it throws a compilation error, because you are not supposed to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

> My guess is that non-constness assumptions for it being passed as non-const b should suffice and allow the modifications, but it's a guess.

Yes, `function` can call non-`const` methods via `b` but not via `a`.

Intuitively, this means that `function` can change an object passed in via the `const` reference `a` if the same object is also passed in via the non-`const` reference `b`.

In general, `const` only makes guarantees about what you can or cannot do with a `const` variable. There may be other variables which refer to the `const` variable, or, to objects within it, that may enable the `const` variable to be modified by a function that doesn't look as though it's modifying a `const` variable.

Coming back to your case, it's upto functions and classes at a higher level than your `function` to themselves enforce constraints about what can and cannot be modified using `const` parameters, member functions, etc.